# Dataset for road accidents or traffic

Tags: data-request, transportation

I am looking for datasets that lists the location of accidents or traffic (latitude and longitude) with date and time in many countries.

I found datasets for USA and UK, now looking for datasets for other countries.

Any type of road accident would be great.

Answer (score 3):

Eurostat has statistics and data on this for European countries:
http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/statistics-explained/index.php/Road_safety_statistics_at_regional_level

All Dutch traffic accident data (in Dutch) can be found here:  https://data.overheid.nl/data/dataset/ngr-verkeersongevallen---bestand-geregistreerde-ongevallen-nederland
 ([permalink](https://data.overheid.nl/data/dataset/b0405c1e-f6bd-419e-93fa-9b3fed33f5c6) in case they change it again)

and this data is shown on a map here:
http://ongelukken.staanhier.nl/

Answer (score 1):

[Here you'll find every French car accidents](https://data.opendatasoft.com/explore/dataset/accidents-corporels-circulation-2015@public/), with location, datetime and much more features.

Hope it helps :)